# Can't access secondary router's settings when linked to primary modem+router

Tags: router, wireless-router, home-networking, setup

I have a router-modem (call it **A**) provided by my ISP, that accesses the internet. I can access this router's settings page normally at its local IP adress at 192.168.100.1. I have connected my home router, **B**, to router A directly by connecting en ethernet output on A to the WAN input on B. They have different SSID-s, both router's are in Bridge mode and they do not share channels. They have different security protocols (WPA/TKIP for A and WPA/AES for B). I can access both wi-fi-s, they are both DHCP, and I have access to the internet even when connecting to B. Previously, router B had a different internal IP: 192.168.0.1 and I could access its settings page when connected to its radio (without internet at that point).

Now that A and B are physically linked, I cannot access the settings page of router B at 192.168.0.1, even when connected directly to its radio. At 192.168.0.1, I end up at the settings page for router A (also at its original location 192.168.100.1), and I cannot see the settings of router B even at the local IP (and port) assigned by the DHCP of router A.

- How can I access the settings page of router B? Is the only option to hook up a computer with it via ethernet cable?
- How can I improve my setup so that there is no double NAT, interference, frequent etc.?

I emphasize, that the setup works, devices can connect normally, and I have access to the internet even when I connect to router B.

Some additional details:

- I need both radios to cover the whole place; ideally, I'd like to have both wireless to provide the same network (same SSID, same security)
- For some reason, router B does not provide a radio signal when in WPA2/TKIP, only as WPA or WPA2/CAE. I read that such a bug exists in TP-Link
- Router A: Compal CH7465VF with stock software
- Router B: Linsys WRT54GL with DD-WRT firmware

Comment: There's a problem with your statement that both routers have DHCP and are bridged. Only B should be in bridge mode, and A should be the only DHCP server.

Comment: @harrymc I see. But in this case, A would not work as a router, would it? I need both radios working to cover the whole house. Also in your proposed setup, both routers should serve the same SSID/security?

Comment: Yes, that's the case when B is in bridge mode. Perhaps you would like to add to the post some details about your setup.

Comment: @harrymc See edit. What else should I add?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access the settings page of router B? Is the only option to hook up a computer with it via ethernet cable?

Most likely, Ethernet vs Wi-Fi will be completely irrelevant – in most home/office routers the two are already bridged to each other (in all modes), so they'll always be in the same IP subnet anyway, and if the whole router is switched to "bridge mode" then both Ethernet *and* Wi-Fi are equally bridged to the upstream network.

There are two options:

1. Bridge B now has a new IP address from the 192.168.100.0 subnet, which it would have received from Router A via DHCP.
2. Bridge B still has the same IP address as before, but your computer doesn't know how to access it, because (numerically) the address is no longer in the computer's "local subnet".

Case 1 would be easiest to deal with: Look through Router A's network client list (or use a network scanning app) to determine Router B's new IP address.

In case 2, temporarily change the computer's IP address to make it in the 192.168.0.0/24 network again. This should make Router B accessible (while everything else becomes temporarily inaccessible); use the opportunity to change Router B's IP address to something in the 192.168.100.0 range.

> They have different security protocols (WPA/TKIP for A and WPA/AES for B).

Don't do that. Use WPA**2**/AES for all networks. (Or even WPA3/AES if you have that.)

Having different security protocols is useless for separation (that's done entirely based on SSIDs); it neither hurts nor helps the IP configuration, but is just completely unnecessary – and not a good idea in general, considering the weakness of TKIP.

Comment: I've already tried Case 1, but it is A's settings page that comes up instad of B's. Is your suggestion based on preliminary settings I should implement?